# Python function that takes a response from Google Ads API and sorts / aggregates it

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api

I am working on this function here and it produces the desired output. I just want to make sure I'm going about things in a smart way.

It effectively just sorts through the data, with consideration to the fact that campaigns may be created by different firms. Then it aggregates the data.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def aggregate_ads(ad_data, labels=list(), default_advertiser='internal'):    
    # Creates dicts to hold data, structured to provide code-readability
    ads_data = defaultdict(
        lambda: defaultdict(
            lambda: defaultdict(int)
        ))
    
    # Lowercases all labels
    labels = map(str.lower, labels)
    
    # Sorts each instance into its channel and adds
    for adgroup in ad_data:
        # Cleans and standardizes campaign name
        campaign_name = adgroup['campaign']['name']
        campaign_name = campaign_name.replace('-', ' ').replace('_', ' ').lower()
        
        # Handling where ad_group type is not provided
        if not adgroup['ad_group'].get('type_'):
            adgroup['ad_group']['type_'] = 'MIXED'
            
        # Collects channel and metrics
        channel = adgroup['ad_group']['type_']
        metrics = dict(
            impressions= int(adgroup['metrics']['impressions']),
            clicks     = int(adgroup['metrics']['clicks']),
            # Converts cost in microns to usd
            cost       = round(int(adgroup['metrics']['cost_micros'])/1000000, 2),
        )
            
        # Checks for labels in campaign name and defaults to specified default
        advertisers = set(labels).intersection(campaign_name.split())
        if not advertisers:
            advertisers.add(default_advertiser)
        
        # Adds the variables to ads_data
        for advertiser in advertisers:
            ads_data[advertiser][channel]['impressions'] += metrics['impressions']
            ads_data[advertiser][channel]['clicks']      += metrics['clicks']
            ads_data[advertiser][channel]['cost']        += metrics['cost']
    
    # Converts into regular dict on return
    return dict(
        (advertiser, dict((ad_type, dict(metrics)) 
                          for ad_type, metrics in ad_data.items())) 
        for advertiser, ad_data in ads_data.items())
```

Here's my output:

```
{'internal': {'DISPLAY_STANDARD': {'clicks': 163,
                                   'cost': 11.8,
                                   'impressions': 6785},
              'MIXED': {'clicks': 6, 'cost': 0.1, 'impressions': 434},
              'SEARCH_STANDARD': {'clicks': 2,
                                  'cost': 5.89,
                                  'impressions': 151}},
 'play': {'MIXED': {'clicks': 5, 'cost': 0.05, 'impressions': 242}}}
```

and some sample input:

```
example = [
 {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'serving_status': 'SERVING',
   'name': 'Google Play Market-USA/Canada-2022-08',
   'start_date': '2022-07-20',
   'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
  'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'type_': 'MIXED'},
  'metrics': {'clicks': '5', 'cost_micros': '54238', 'impressions': '242'},
  'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
  'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
 {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'serving_status': 'SERVING',
   'name': 'Google Play Market-USA/Canada-2022-08',
   'start_date': '2022-07-20',
   'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
  'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'type_': 'MIXED'},
  'metrics': {'clicks': '3', 'cost_micros': '53943', 'impressions': '217'},
  'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
  'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
 {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'serving_status': 'SERVING',
   'name': 'Google Play Market-USA/Canada-2022-08',
   'start_date': '2022-07-20',
   'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
  'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'type_': 'MIXED'},
  'metrics': {'clicks': '3', 'cost_micros': '53943', 'impressions': '217'},
  'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
  'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
 {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'serving_status': 'SERVING',
   'name': 'Display-Global-Desktop-202208',
   'start_date': '2022-07-21',
   'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
  'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'type_': 'DISPLAY_STANDARD'},
  'metrics': {'clicks': '95', 'cost_micros': '6036546', 'impressions': '4186'},
  'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
  'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
 {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'serving_status': 'SERVING',
   'name': 'Search-USA/NOTES',
   'start_date': '2022-08-30',
   'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
  'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'type_': 'SEARCH_STANDARD'},
  'metrics': {'clicks': '2', 'cost_micros': '5890000', 'impressions': '151'},
  'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
  'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
 {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'serving_status': 'SERVING',
   'name': 'Display-Global--Desktop-Files',
   'start_date': '2022-09-02',
   'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
  'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'type_': 'DISPLAY_STANDARD'},
  'metrics': {'clicks': '68', 'cost_micros': '5757098', 'impressions': '2599'},
  'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
   'status': 'ENABLED',
   'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
  'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}}
]
```

```
labels = ['play'] # In reality, this is partner labels they'd put in the campaign name

aggregate_ads(example, labels)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a critical bug. You assign a `map` to `labels`, but this is never materialised and so is consumed and subsequently looks like an empty collection.

I'm going to suggest that you throw away most of your implementation and replace it with Pandas, which is well-suited to your case. The entry point will be putting your example code through `pd.json_normalize`, which will give you a data frame that has six rows for your example data.

Replacing your dict generators with Pandas `to_dict`, and performing the sum in a vectorised manner instead of in a loop, your code could look like the following:

```
from pprint import pprint

import pandas as pd


def aggregate_ads(ad_data: dict, labels: set[str], default_advertiser: str = 'internal') -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.json_normalize(ad_data).astype({
        'metrics.clicks': int,
        'metrics.cost_micros': int,
        'metrics.impressions': int,
    })
    df['channel'] = df['ad_group.type_'].fillna('MIXED')
    df['metrics.cost'] = df['metrics.cost_micros'] / 1e6

    campaign_fragments = (
        df['campaign.name']
        .str.replace('-', ' ').str.replace('_', ' ').str.lower().str.split()
        .apply(set).apply(labels.__and__)
    )
    campaign_fragments[campaign_fragments == set()] = default_advertiser
    df['advertisers'] = campaign_fragments

    return (
        df.explode('advertisers')
        .groupby(['advertisers', 'channel'])
        ['metrics.impressions', 'metrics.clicks', 'metrics.cost']
        .sum()
        .rename(columns={
            'metrics.impressions': 'impressions',
            'metrics.clicks': 'clicks',
            'metrics.cost': 'cost',
        })
    )


def ads_to_json(groups: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    inners = groups.groupby(level=0).apply(
        lambda df: df.droplevel(0).to_dict('index'))
    return inners.to_dict()


def test() -> None:
    example = [
        {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'serving_status': 'SERVING',
                      'name': 'Google Play Market-USA/Canada-2022-08',
                      'start_date': '2022-07-20',
                      'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
         'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'status': 'ENABLED',
                      'type_': 'MIXED'},
         'metrics': {'clicks': '5', 'cost_micros': '54238', 'impressions': '242'},
         'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                         'status': 'ENABLED',
                         'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
        {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'serving_status': 'SERVING',
                      'name': 'Google Play Market-USA/Canada-2022-08',
                      'start_date': '2022-07-20',
                      'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
         'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'status': 'ENABLED',
                      'type_': 'MIXED'},
         'metrics': {'clicks': '3', 'cost_micros': '53943', 'impressions': '217'},
         'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                         'status': 'ENABLED',
                         'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
        {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'serving_status': 'SERVING',
                      'name': 'Google Play Market-USA/Canada-2022-08',
                      'start_date': '2022-07-20',
                      'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
         'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'status': 'ENABLED',
                      'type_': 'MIXED'},
         'metrics': {'clicks': '3', 'cost_micros': '53943', 'impressions': '217'},
         'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                         'status': 'ENABLED',
                         'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
        {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'serving_status': 'SERVING',
                      'name': 'Display-Global-Desktop-202208',
                      'start_date': '2022-07-21',
                      'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
         'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'status': 'ENABLED',
                      'type_': 'DISPLAY_STANDARD'},
         'metrics': {'clicks': '95', 'cost_micros': '6036546', 'impressions': '4186'},
         'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                         'status': 'ENABLED',
                         'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
        {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'serving_status': 'SERVING',
                      'name': 'Search-USA/NOTES',
                      'start_date': '2022-08-30',
                      'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
         'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'status': 'ENABLED',
                      'type_': 'SEARCH_STANDARD'},
         'metrics': {'clicks': '2', 'cost_micros': '5890000', 'impressions': '151'},
         'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                         'status': 'ENABLED',
                         'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}},
        {'campaign': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'serving_status': 'SERVING',
                      'name': 'Display-Global--Desktop-Files',
                      'start_date': '2022-09-02',
                      'end_date': '2037-12-30'},
         'ad_group': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                      'status': 'ENABLED',
                      'type_': 'DISPLAY_STANDARD'},
         'metrics': {'clicks': '68', 'cost_micros': '5757098', 'impressions': '2599'},
         'ad_group_ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah',
                         'status': 'ENABLED',
                         'ad': {'resource_name': 'blahblahbah'}},
         'segments': {'date': '2022-10-11'}}
    ]

    grouped = aggregate_ads(example, labels={'play'})
    js = ads_to_json(grouped)
    pprint(js)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! You're clearly much more advanced than I am, and I'm excited learn how all of this functions. A quick question though, what is "labels.\_\_and\_\_" ? Specifically, \_\_and\_\_

Comment: That's a tricky bit of dunder magic that actually means "use a function binding to the `&` operator, which in this case is set intersection"